# More then two filters in OneSignal create Notification

Tags: filter, notifications, onesignal

I'm using filters in create notifications with onesignal. I want to use 3 or more filters at a time but one filter must match and others can be optional. Read the docs but can't find option like this.

**What I want?**

Let say I have following 3 filters

- country
- language
- tag ( having key type and value 'premium' )

I want to send notification to users only from US, either having language english or type premium.

**What I tried?**

```js
[
 {field: "country", relation: "=", value: "US"},
 {operator: "AND"}, 
 {field: "language", relation: "=", value: "en"},
 {operator: "OR"}, 
 {field: "tag", key: "type", relation: "=", value: "premium"}
]
```

this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking to support, I found we need to AND required filter with every other filter that is optional. Using above example from question which is:

Let say I have following 3 filters:

- Country
- Language
- Tag ( having key type and value 'premium' )

If I want to send notification to users only from US, either having language english or type premium. I have to AND country with Language and Tag filter.

So my filter's array will look like this:

```js
[
 {field: "language", relation: "=", value: "en"},
 {operator: "AND"}, 
 {field: "country", relation: "=", value: "US"},
 {operator: "OR"}, 
 {field: "tag", key: "type", relation: "=", value: "premium"}
 {operator: "AND"}, 
 {field: "country", relation: "=", value: "US"},
]
```

**Note**: According to [docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#filter-usage), only 200 filters are allowed including operators